# MYSQL: How can insert into a table a variable, depending on the variable if its not null?

Tags: mysql, variables, null, insert

My example code:

```
SET @VARIABLE1 := 'Heyho';
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
insert into Test(id, title) values(2, (SELECT @VARIABLE1));
insert into Test(id, title) values(3, (SELECT @VARIABLE2 WHERE @VARIABLE2 IS NOT NULL));
select * from Test;
```

My actual results:

```
id  title
1   Hello
2   Heyho
3   NULL
```

My expected results:

```
id  title
1   Hello
2   Heyho
```

I only want to insert my row with ID 3 if the @VARIABLE2 Is not null

Comment: ```insert into Test(id, title) SELECT 3, @VARIABLE2 WHERE @VARIABLE2 IS NOT NULL;``` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b80a253df62922e29f03dfa6b8e21c2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Akina's comment the correct code is:

```
SET @VARIABLE1 := 'Heyho';
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
insert into Test(id, title) SELECT 2, @VARIABLE1 WHERE @VARIABLE1 IS NOT NULL;
insert into Test(id, title) SELECT 3, @VARIABLE2 WHERE @VARIABLE2 IS NOT NULL;
select * from Test;
```

It works now, I get the expected results!